# Parse.com number of regex find operations

Tags: regex, parse-platform

After developing a bit on the Parse.com backend, I've found myself getting an error:

> The number of regex find operations in progress has reached its limit

It is a similar error to this one: [Here](https://parse.com/questions/code-154the-number-of-count-operations-in-progress-has-reached-its-limit-code-154-version-1125)

In the above link, it is stated that the limit is 160 requests per minute for the entire application with no mention of pricing teirs and how they affect the limit.

I can't find anywhere that specifies the exact number of regex requests allowed at a time.

There are several mentions similar to this issue on Stack Overflow and other places, but none of them refer to the actual value of the limitation.

**tl;dr**

What is the exact number of regex requests allowed by parse for various price points?

**NOTE:**
I am not asking for general API request limits.  There appears to be a separate and unpublished limit specifically pertaining to Regex find requests.  This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The default limit is `30` requests/**second**. You can find the the pricing for a particular request limit (per app) using their online calculator (https://www.parse.com/plans). If you want to increase your limit to more than 200 req/sec, you will have to request a custom setup.

Their [FAQ section](https://www.parse.com/plans/faq) answers questions like:

- What happens if your app exceeds the default 30 requests/second limit
- How frequently you can increase or decrease your request limit

Comment: This is for general API requests.  There is a different limit for regex find requests.